# How can I update the value of a field in every row of a list?

Tags: c#

I have this class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int DoubleNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and a list

```
List<Test> myTestList;
```

How can I make the value of the field DoubleNumber in `myTestList` equal to twice the value of Number? Note that I am okay to create another list if that's needed.

Comment: you mean foreach? or will `DoubleNumber` always be 2x `Number`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for this? The simplest way would be to define DoubleNumber in the class to simply return Number*2 and get rid of the setter (unless you want that to make Number = value/2, but you are into the murky realms of odd numbers then).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
foreach(Test item in myList) {
  item.DoubleNumber = 2*item.Number;
}
```

Or, if it's ok, just remove the setter and modify the getter to return 2x `Number`:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int DoubleNumber { get { return 2* this.Number; } } //completely remove setter
}
```

Or, if you still want to be able to modify `DoubleNumber`:

```
public class Test {
  private int m_num;
  private int m_doubleNum;

  public string Id {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public int Number {
    get {
      return this.m_num;
    }
    set {
      this.m_num = value;
      this.m_doubleNum = 2 * value; //when Number is set, update m_doubleNum too
    }
  }
  public int DoubleNumber {
    get {
      return this.m_doubleNum;
    }
    set {
      this.m_doubleNum = value; //allow manual setting of DoubleNumber
      //or maybe also modify Number here?
      //this.m_num = value / 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way it could be using a `foreach` statement:

```
foreach(var item in myTestList)
{
    item.DoubleNumber = 2*item.Number;
}
```

Another way it could be to use LINQ.

```
var result = myTestList.Select(test => new Test 
                       { 
                           test.Id, 
                           test.Number, 
                           DoubleNumber = 2*test.Number; 
                       })
                       .ToList();
```

Among the two ways I would prefer the first one, since it's more clear what you are trying to do and more performant (in the second approach you have to create a new object for each object in `myTestList`).